# Synonym for "secondaire" without the "accessoire" connotation

Tags: synonymes

I'm looking for a French synonym for "secondaire" which doesn't have that connotation that the thing is accessory (not necessary).
The sense I would want is something that is built on something else that is "primaire".
I've been thinking about "complexe, composé", but it doesn't feel quite right..
I can't even find a word in English.

Comment: I don't think "secondaire" necessarily have a negative connotation, especially if it's used next to "primaire". It's used in this way for education or geological eras for example. However, if you used "primaire" in the sense "very simple", "at the lower lever of complexity", you'll need a different word but not because of connotations.

Comment: Can ou give us the sentence for reference? Because it's is hard to give advice without the context.

Comment: maybe subsidiaire or auxiliaire

Comment: @Calins, Ce ne serait pas dans une phrase, mais à mettre dans des slides pour une présentation  en mathématiques. J'ai des éléments primaires, que je considère comme étant des éléments de base. Et ensuite, j'ai des éléments qui sont définis à partir de ces éléments primaires, ils sont "construits" avec. (construit dans le sens mathématique).
Donc je cherche un adjectif pour ces deuxièmes éléments.

Comment: @Baptiste, subsidiaire ou auxiliaire ont cette connotation de "non nécessaire", que j'aimerais justement éviter.

Comment: @Teleporting Goat, oui c'est vrai que dans ces contextes, ça ne porte pas cette connotation, mais comme là le contexte n'y est pas, j'aurais aimé trouver le mot qui va bien :)

Comment: "de base" pour les primaires et "complexes" pour les secondaires, ça me semble bien. Qu'est-ce qui vous gêne ? Ou "élémentaires" vs "composés" ?

Comment: What about "dérivé"?

Comment: Effectivement, je crois que élémentaire/composé, ou primaire/composé sont ceux qui me vont le mieux, je ne suis pas sûr qu'il existe mieux...
@Nico, "dérivé" aurait effectivement été très bien, mais je suis dans un contexte mathématique, et donc cela fait trop référence au principe de dérivée.

Comment: Pourquoi poser cette question en anglais alors que tu sembles être on ne peut plus francophone ?

Comment: de premier niveau et de deuxième niveau

Comment: @jlliagre, parce que je suis nouveau sur ce site, et que je ne savais pas trop si je devais la poser en français ou en anglais sachant que c'est un site anglais qui parle de la langue française.

Comment: Ok, pas de problème. C'était juste pour comprendre. Tu devrais éditer ta question et répondre rapidement aux demandes de clarification car ta question est en passe d'être fermée pour manque de détails et clarté.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a word that fits better than "composé", so I'll just stick with that.
Thank you all for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 3):

An example would be useful. I will try fo figure out one.

> Son fusil enrayé, il sortit son arme secondaire.

Perhaps *deuxième*.

> Son fusil enrayé, il sortit sa deuxième arme.

I don't feel this *deuxième* weapon is accessory.

Perhaps *complémentaire*, but the sentence won't be natural. It will more likely be:

> Son arme principale enrayée, il sortit son arme secondaire.

This arme *secondaire* is not accessory, here it's the correct word in French.

Others candidates: *alternatif* (somewhat critized in formal French because *une alternative* is not another option, but both options as a whole), *adjoint, associé, d'appui, d'appoint*..

Comment: Pour une arme, ce serait plutôt *de secours* : par définition un guerrier manie une arme, ou un type d’arme, et doit avoir une solution *de secours* lorsque son arme est hors d’usage.

Comment: Cela dit, Dominique Venner (*Le Livre des armes*, vol. *Pistolets et Revolvers*, La Pensée moderne, 1974) consacre tout un chapitre à "La deuxième arme", dont le propos est de démontrer précisément qu'une telle arme, si elle est bien "de secours", n'en est pas pour autant *secondaire* (pour des raisons surtout psychologiques), d'où cette expression de "deuxième arme".

Comment: Merci, mais tous ces exemples sont très spécifiques à des armes, et il n'y a pas du tout l'idée que le second est construit à partir du premier. Je pense que "composé" est le mieux que je puisse trouver.

Comment: Cet aspect de composition m'avait en effet échappé. Mais puisque ma réponse était plutôt "armurière", un autre mot me vient, pour ce qu'il vaut : *modulaire*.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you are looking for is "*dérivé*".

Example:
*"Le kérosène est dérivé du pétrole brut"*

Comment: See my response to @Nico's comment.